# One table with two different tasks

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I got a test from my lecturer, I have to make one table with 3 columns inside: `prodName`, `Qty`, and `totSalesToDate`. Column `Qty` shows how many products have been sold in the input date, and `totSalesToDate` indicates products have been sold during the beginning of a month until the input date. Here is the example result table:

```
prodName    |   Qty     |   totSalesToDate
Car         |    2      |       10
Bicycle     |    8      |       22
Truck       |    1      |        7
Motor-cycle |    3      |       12
```

I have to make this table using stored procedure (TSQL) with no subqueries. So far, the queries I made is:

```
create procedure SalesReport @date varchar(10)
as
    select p.prodName,  sum(s.Qty) as Qty
    from PeriodTime pt full join Sales s on pt.Time = s.Time full join Product p on s.prodID = p.prodID
    where @date = pt.Date
    group by p.prodName
    union
    select p.prodName, sum(s.Qty) as totSalesToDate
    from PeriodTime pt full join Sales s on pt.Time = s.Time full join Product p on s.prodID = p.prodID
    where pt.Date between '2010060' and @date and p.prodName is not null
    group by p.prodName
go
```

But the result I get is like this:

```
prodName    |   Qty
Car         |    2   
Car         |   10
Bicycle     |    8 
Bicycle     |   22
Truck       |    1     
Truck       |    7
Motor-cycle |    3     
Motor-cycle |   12
```

Anybody can help? I've been googling around but still cannot find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified the existing schema and data you are querying rather than leaving readers to reverse engineer it from your attempted query.

Comment: sorry, where is to view the existing schema in sql server management studio 2012? I'm really really newbie in tsql.. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
create procedure SalesReport @date varchar(10)
as
select p.prodName,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN @date = pt.Date THEN s.Qty ELSE 0 END) as Qty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN pt.Date between '2010060' and @date THEN s.Qty ELSE 0.0 END) AS totSalesToDate
from PeriodTime pt full join Sales s on pt.Time = s.Time full join Product p on s.prodID = p.prodID

group by p.prodName
go
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried but sum(case..when..) seems didn't work. My table contains 3 columns now but the values of totSalesToDate  are exactly same with values of Qty.

Comment: Trying running the select without the `group by` to show the non grouped results. Verify that you are seeing 0.0 where expected

Comment: Without group by, I got this error message: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SalesReport, Line 3
Column 'dbo.Product.prodName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Try the whole thing now. Review the difference between grouped and non grouped queries

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It really worked! By the way, I just knew that we can put case..when.. inside sum() and select statement. Is it subquery or not?